# The application can not access the phone book

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontactstore

I am suffering for several days in an attempt to access the names and numbers phonebook and all failed. I use the following code, which works successfully in the test application, but when I add it to your project work, it does not work. Variable "granted" constantly has a value - "false" and I get the error "Access Failure". Despite this, in the privacy settings is not displayed slider to allow access ...
I have long could not find the answer to a rather strange behavior ...

I would be grateful for any help!`

```
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted == YES) {

        NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
        NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
        } else {
            for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {

                TSContact *newContact = [[TSContact alloc] init];
                newContact.firstName = contact.givenName;
                newContact.lastName = contact.familyName;
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                newContact.image = image;
                for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                    NSString *phone = [label.value stringValue];
                    if ([phone length] > 0) {
                        [contacts addObject:phone];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error = %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

Comment: What is the deployment target of your app (target iOS version 6.0 something)?

Comment: Have you added `Privacy - Contacts Usage Description` key in your info.plist? Its supported in iOS 6.0 and later.

Comment: I tried iOS ios 8 and 9 still does not work

Comment: I added just "Privacy - Contacts Usage Description" in the info.plist, but access switch has not appeared in your privacy settings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access information of existing contacts in your address book following code may help you :)

**Step 1** : Add

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

**Step 2 :** call following Method from viewDidLoad

```
-(void)phonenumber
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true;
    ABAuthorizationStatus status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();

    if (status == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
        // if you got here, user had previously denied/revoked permission for your
        // app to access the contacts, and all you can do is handle this gracefully,
        // perhaps telling the user that they have to go to settings to grant access
        // to contacts

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"This app requires access to your contacts to function properly. Please visit to the \"Privacy\" section in the iPhone Settings app." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (!addressBook) {
        NSLog(@"ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions error: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
        return;
    }

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion error: %@", CFBridgingRelease(error));
        }

        if (granted) {
            // if they gave you permission, then just carry on
            [self listPeopleInAddressBook:addressBook];
        } else {
            // however, if they didn't give you permission, handle it gracefully, for example...
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // BTW, this is not on the main thread, so dispatch UI updates back to the main queue
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"This app requires access to your contacts to function properly. Please visit to the \"Privacy\" section in the iPhone Settings app." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            });
        }
        CFRelease(addressBook);
    });
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

**Step 3 :** Add This Method also to your code 
This method gives you all required information for particular contact.

```
- (void)listPeopleInAddressBook:(ABAddressBookRef)addressBook
{
            //Run UI Updates
            NSArray *allPeople = CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook));
            NSInteger numberOfPeople = [allPeople count];

            for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
                ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allPeople[i];
                //From Below code you can get what you want.
                NSString *firstName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
                NSString *lastName  = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
                NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);

                ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                NSString *phoneNumber = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0));
                NSLog(@"phone:%@", phoneNumber);
                NSLog(@"=============================================");
            }

}
```

Comment: I added your code in my application, and, unfortunately, an alert of access is displayed each time the application starts. When transition in the settings for access to the contacts, and the slider is not displayed :(

Comment: Have you got what you want from my code?
i'm not getting what exactly problem you are facing? @СашаЦвигун

Comment: No, I have not received contact from your code. My application does not have access to them. The privacy settings, there is no switch to allow access ...

Comment: No, no mistakes does not give xcode. I pass breakpoint, stop in a few places, but there are no errors. I went to the block dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue () that causes the alert and all. In the privacy settings switch to allow access to the contacts does not appear... very strange

Comment: are you sure you are going with this for accessing contacts from Setting?
settings> general>restrictions>privacy and allow changes.

Comment: I can send you a project you try to build an on your computer. Only give your email

Comment: Here you go
iamiosguy@gmail.com

Comment: I sent to the e mail